# Using ngCookies in a ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to include ngCookies in a project. The angular cookies library is included in my index.html after the ionic.bundle.
I can see on the network tab of the developer tools that it is actually loading. Angular doesn't show any error when loading the page, as it usually does when a module is missing. The problem is that, when in my code I try to access the functions of the $cookies service, the $cookies variable is actually pointing to an empty object. 
Here are some relevant code snippets:
On the definition of my app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ionic',
'ngCookies',
'ngMessages',
'rt.eventemitter',
'myApp.views']);
```

On my factory:

```
 angular.module('myApp.views')
   .factory('UserStore', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$cookies', '$timeout', 
        function($rootScope, $q, $cookies, $timeout){
           var user = {};
           function setSessionId(sessionId){
                console.log(">> setting sessionId to:",sessionId);
                user.sessionId = sessionId;
                $cookies.put('sessionId', user.sessionId);
           }
           return{ setSessionId:setSessionId}
        }
]);
```

In this case, when I try to call the setSessionId method I get an error that $cookies.put is not a function since, as I mentioned above, $cookies is just an empty object.

Any Ideas?

Comment: it depends on which angular version you use! they changed a lot in angular 1.4..  in angular 1.3 when you set a cookie you can just assign it: ``$cookies.sessionId = user.sessionId;``

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks. I am porting an existing web app to ionic and the web app is using version 1.4 which Ionic doesn't support yet. This is going to be fun. PD. Too bad you didn't posted your comment as an answer, since you did actually answered my question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

it depends on which angular version you use!

they changed a lot in angular 1.4.. in angular 1.3 when you set a cookie you can just assign it:

`$cookies.sessionId = user.sessionId;`